# vb.net pointers as parameters in .dll call

Tags: vb.net, dll

I am trying to include a dll (ehlapi32.dll) so I can attach to an old green screen application and get some data pulled into vb.net.

I have the dll defined and am trying to call it but I am not sure I am doing it correctly.  The IBM documentation says the values have to be pointers to the parameters.

```
Public Class Form1
Declare Auto Function hllapi Lib "c:\Program Files\Quick3270\ehlapi32.dll" (
    ByVal i1 As IntPtr,
    ByVal s1 As System.Text.StringBuilder,
    ByVal i2 As IntPtr,
    ByVal i3 As IntPtr) As Integer
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim RetVal As Integer = 0
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder("A")
    Dim p1 As IntPtr = 1
    Dim p2 As IntPtr = 0
    Dim p3 As IntPtr = 0

    RetVal = hllapi(p1, sb, p2, p3)
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: When I click on Button 1, I get the message "Invalid Return Code Pointe.  Parameter cannot be NULL."

Comment: I would think that if you passing values, then you need to pass the address of each variable - not a copy. Thus the ByVal should be byrefs.